# When I convert my particle system, the number of leaves increases drastically

Tags: modeling, modifiers, customization

When I convert my particle system, the number of leaves increases drastically; I do not want this.

[image]

Comment: I dont know what mean "Convert" in modifiers. I want only accept particle without gowing up leafs.

Comment: Problem solved. I have particles system in leafs, i delete and its ok. particle system must be in tree not in leafs.

Comment: You need to click Convert just *once*